# Find and change element's textContent without breaking DOM events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to find an element and replace the `.textContent` of it within a constantly changing table.  I'm fairly new to coding, but I've come across an issue when trying to replace certain elements' `.textContent`.

I have a table on my website that shuffles the values upon every new session. I would like to have certain values within that table to be replaced.

```
<table class = "tb">
  <tr>
    <td>Element 1</td>
    <td>Element 2</td>
    <td>Element 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And upon each new session, the order of each element is changed.

I want to first find "Element 2" and change it to "Element 2.1", but I cannot do it with my current script because it just changes the 2nd row of the table rather than what I am looking for. So upon reshuffling, it might change Element 1 to the replacement value instead.

I have a very simple script to swap out elements.

```
const Tableswap = () => {
    const findele = document.querySelectorAll(".tb")[1];
    if (findele === null){
        return;
    };
    findele.textContent = "Element 2.1";
};
```

I've tried the following to find the particular element that I am looking for, but I am not sure where to go from here:

```
//find the required element

function contains(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
}

const finder = contains('.tb', "Element 2");

if (finder === null){
    return;
};
finder.tb.textContent = "Element 2.1";
```

I am honestly not sure if I even went in the right direction with all of this, and I am a complete newbie when it comes to all of this, I've basically been scavenging bits of code from everywhere and trying to understand what I'm doing along the way. I would prefer everything to be in JS, as I have absolutely no experience with JQuery and have no clue what it even is.

Comment: Use the [`id` global property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Comment: @Kitswas Do you mean to set an ID to each entry in the table and then reference to them by that?

Comment: `Id`s for the elements you want to access directly via JS.

Comment: From the contents of your question, I feel we have an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kitswas Possibly the case. 

I am trying to change the text.Content of a specific item in the table without having to alter the table itself. The item in question is in a random position upon each new session, and I need to find it and change the text.Content of it via a new JS script. Something similar to the "Find and Replace" function you can see in most text Editors nowadays.

Comment: 'I am trying to change the text.Content of a specific item in the table' - Give it an `id`. And then, [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: @Kitswas Is there any way to do so without altering the HTML?

Comment: 'specific item' - How can we recognize that item? What are its distinguishing features?

Comment: Your first script has a problem. `document.querySelectorAll(".tb")` should be `document.querySelectorAll(".tb td")`.

Comment: Something similar to a function that searches for specific text.Content, and then replaces said text.Content with new value? 

Oh and thanks for pointing out the mistake! Completely missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you were trying to achieve through the second script.
I tried to keep it close to your orginal code to make it easier for you to comprehend.

The script should be `defer`red if loaded externally to prevent it from executing before the DOM has finished loading.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <table class="tb">
      <tr>
        <td>Element 1</td>
        <td>Element 2</td>
        <td>Element 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script> //defer if loading via src, keep it at the end otherwise
      function findAndReplace(selector, find, replace) {
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function (element) {
          if (RegExp(find).test(element.textContent))
            element.textContent = replace;
        });
      }
      findAndReplace(".tb td", "Element 2", "Element 2.1");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Many thanks for your patience and understanding!

It turns out, it was an XY Problem. I'll keep in mind to keep my questions concise and straight to the point next time around!

Comment: Oh and the bit about defer, I didn't even know you can do that, is that why the "replace" method does not get in the way of the DOM events? 

I'll properly dissect the snippet to get a better understanding of it!

Comment: @Gallyho I forgot to mention this in my answer. If this script is inline, put it at the end.
The defer attribute is only for external scripts. The defer attribute is ignored if the <script> tag has no src.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This was indeed an external script, and I had trouble with some of my functions breaking DOM events, and I had to come up with god knows how many workarounds to make everything function properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, change it to `<td id="myID">`, and then you can use `document.getElementById(myID).innerHTML = "Element 2.1"`.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, my question might be lacking. I have to work around the html code that is set. 

Perhaps I can append the "ID" to the table from within the new JS? Would that be a workaround?